# Efficiently return a ChatColor

Tags: java, performance, beginner, enum, minecraft

I am working on a plugin for a Minecraft server. In it, I have a function that returns a `ChatColor` depending on what permission level you are.

Whenever I need reference the user with proper colors, I always get a color from the below function.

```
/**
 * ChatColor
 *
 * @param Player
 * @return ChatColor
 */
public ChatColor getColor(Player p) {
    // By default the color is Guest. The color will stay at guest otherwise.
    ChatColor color = ChatColor.GRAY;
    if (p.hasPermission("level.owner")) {
        // Owner
        color = ChatColor.RED;
    } else if (p.hasPermission("level.staff")) {
        // Admin / Mod
        color = ChatColor.AQUA;
    } else if (p.hasPermission("level.builder")) {
        // Builder
        color = ChatColor.DARK_AQUA;
    } else if (p.hasPermission("level.member")) {
        // Member
        color = ChatColor.GOLD;
    } else if (p.hasPermission("level.guest")) {
        // Guest
        // We don't need to change the color, since the color defaults to gray.
    }
    return color;
}
```

One might call this function as below:

```
p.sendMessage("Welcome back, " + getColor(p) + p.getName() + gold + "!");
```

And it would send a message to the player like "Welcome back, *(playerName)*!" with playerName the level's color.

What I have found is that if you have the first permission level (`level.owner`) it can take a much longer time. After putting in some debugging (e.g getting a NanoTime, running my function, and subtracting the difference) I've found the following:

- With `level.owner` it takes about 4580ns to run
- With `level.staff` it takes about 6340ns to run
- With `level.builder` it takes about 8000ns to run
- With `level.member` it takes about 7630ns (sometimes going as high as 10240ns) to run
- With `level.guest` it takes about 10000ns+ to run

Is there any way to improve my function run at nearly the same speed for all of my checks?

(I am a beginner at Java, but know many other languages, so this is somewhat new to me.)

Comment: Sounds like the performance issue has to do with `p.hasPermission`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing that you call this method frequently.  If so, you might consider memoizing the result.  Something like

```
private Map<Player, ChatColor> playerChatColors = new HashMap<>();
```

in the class.  Possibly make this `static`.  And then at the beginning of the method, replace

> ```
>     ChatColor color = ChatColor.GRAY;
> ```

with

```
    ChatColor color = playerChatColors.get(p);
    if (color != null) {
        return color;
    }
    color = ChatColor.GRAY;
```

And then before the `return` at the end, add something like

```
    playerChatColors.put(p, color);
```

I don't know if this is faster or not.  In the typical case, it will just do a single hash access.  If that is fast, then it's faster.  If that's slow, then it might not be.

There's also the problem that if the permissions change, this won't adjust.   I'm assuming that this will be rare enough not to matter.  If that's not so, you might need to find a way to invalidate the caching when permissions change.  Of course, if you invalidate too often, you lose the benefits of caching.  The first call to this method will be slower.  It's the subsequent calls that this might help.

Comment: Thank you extremely much for your answer! While it won't completely remove the slowness of .hasPermission(), it will speed up subsequent calls.

Answer (score 5):

Nice code! It was fun to review. Note that I do not know how this API you are using works, so I've made quite a few assumptions about it. Also, I've some assumptions about your knowledge of Java (despite your post) because you said you were familiar with other programming languages, so if you have any questions you can ask me in a comment.

---

### Different times

The reason why you have different times for each level is because of these `else if`s. Since this is a chain of `else if`s, when one passes, the entire rest of the chain is skipped.

That means, the player is `level.owner`, as soon as that first check passes, the rest of the checks are completely skipped and the color is returned. However, if the user is a `level.guest`, the execution has to go through the entire chain before checking for `level.guest`.

A way you could possibly even these out would be to remove the `else` part of each conditional. That way, each conditional has to be at least checked before the `return` statement is reached.

However, I don't see why you would want to do that because if it's possible to keep your function fast like it is now, then there is no point in trying to make it slower so the speeds are even.

In fact, you could make this function even a bit faster by `return`ing the color as soon as the correct conditional is met.

---

### Converting to `switch`

Now, I don't know exactly how this API that you are using works, so this next part may not work.

You could try to speed up your code even more/make it more cleaner than it is right now by storing the player's permission level in the player object itself. Then, you could easily use a `switch` to re-write your code:

```
switch(p.permissionLevel) {
    case "level.owner":
        break;
    case "level.staff":
        break;
    ...
}
```

This `permissionLevel` field would most likely be set to the right level in the constructor of this player object.

Now, your code is faster because you don't have to keep calling that `hasPermission` method. Also, it looks much cleaner in the form of a loop.

---

### Permission enum

Right now, you are checking what permission a player has by using this `hasPermission` method with these arbitrary strings. While this is okay, it could be made much more cleaner and idiomatic using an enum.

Say you had this enum:

```
public enum PermissionLevel {
    OWNER, STAFF, BUILDER...
}
```

Now, the different levels of permission are stored in one convenient place. Instead of using strings to represent the different levels, you should now use something like this.

But wait, there's more:

With this, you could also make this `getColor` method more efficient, along with future methods by storing the corresponding chat color with each enum. Here is what I mean:

```
public enum PermissionLevel {
    OWNER(ChatColor.RED), STAFF(ChatColor.AQUA)...

    ... etc methods etc...
}
```

Using that, you could now make this `getColor` method have O(1) speed:

```
public ChatColor getColor(Player p) {
    return p.permission.chatColor;
}
```

This completely eliminates the need for any conditionals and function calls, thus speeding up your code by a lot.

Comment: The `switch` won't work.  There are a set of permission levels, not a single one.  See [Player](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html) and click through to [Permissible](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/permissions/Permissible.html).

Comment: @mdfst13 You could fix that with removing the `break` in a few places, right?

Comment: No.  You can't switch on a `Collection` in Java.  You need it to return a `String`, but you will actually get a `Set` from `getPermissibles`.  I.e. the problem is in what you call and can't be fixed from this method.

Comment: Thank you for your review! It's extremely informative. As @mdfst13 said, there is a set of permission levels. My example was with "level.staff", however the player could also have the permission "minecraft.toggledownfall", and an infinite quanity more.

Comment: Oh jeez, I guess that invalidates my answer. Would you like me to tear it down?

Comment: @SirPython Not at all. I can reverse my if/elseifs and put returns in them, so guests first, then members, and so on.

Comment: Again, thank you extremely much for your answer. I'm going to choose @mdfst13's answer because it solved speed, but your answer definitely told me that I need to redo the way I check permissions.

Comment: @awesomebing1 Sure thing!